# Convertion obj json react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have one json:

fakeApi.js:

```
{
  "offSet": [
    {
      "code": "AB",
      "price": "1032"
    }
    {
      "code": "CD",
      "price": "1054"
    }
    {
      "code": "EF",
      "price": "2042"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert the "code" to text, example:

AB has to display Alfa Bravo
CD has to display Charlie Delta
EF has to display Eco Foxtrot

App.js

```
import React from { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import fakeApi from './fakeApi.js';

function App() {
  const sus = fakeApi.offSet;

  const getConvert = () => {
    const fake = sus.map(place => place.code);

    switch(fake) {
      case "AB":
        return <Text>Alfa Bravo</Text>
      case "CD":
        return <Text>Charlie Delta</Text>
      case "EF":
        return <Text>Eco Foxtrot</Text>
      default:
        return <Text>error</Text>
    }    
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {sus.map(place => (
        <View>
          <Text>{place.CODECONVERTIDO}</Text>
          <Text>{place.price}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The convertion is correct? Where am i missing?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this your error you match array with string in `switch case`

`const fake = sus.map(place => place.code);` this is return array

`case "AB":` but here you macth array with string

so your switch shoud be

```js
const getConvert = (code) => {
    switch(code) {
      case "AB":
        return <Text>Alfa Bravo</Text>
      case "CD":
        return <Text>Charlie Delta</Text>
      case "EF":
        return <Text>Eco Foxtrot</Text>
      default:
        return <Text>error</Text>
    }    
  }
```

and use it in your render function like this

```js
   {sus.map(
     place => (
       <View>
          <Text>{getConvert(place.code)}</Text>
          <Text>{place.price}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your map function returns an array, which must be iterated through using a loop.

You cannot run switch on an array to create an iterator.

Use your map callback to manipulate the code to text, and return both elements of the array. Something like....

```js
    const convertedCode = sus.map(place => {
      let placeConversion = null;
      switch(place.code) {
           ...
           placeConversion = ...
      }
      return { price: place.price, converted: placeConverted }
    });
```